# Type root password until password is ok in a C Shell Script

Tags: shell, while-loop, csh, su

I'm scripting a little tool for my company that helps users install certain version of a given software on a Centos machine. To do so, I created a csh script. At the end, to install the said software, the user must be root, so in my script, I ask the user to type in his/her root password.

My issue is that if, for some reason, the user makes a mistake while typing his/her root password, my script exits.

So I'm looking for a way to allow the user several tries, let's say, 3.

So far, in my script, I simply do a:

```
su -c "chmod +x '${installPackageName}${dir}/installerAsRoot.sh'; cd ${installPackageName}${dir}; ./installerAsRoot.sh"
```

I tried some `while`/`do` loops but my knowledge of `su` is quite inexistant. I also thought of a way of catching the return value of `su` when the password is wrong (125  or -3) but I'm not sure how to combine `eval` or `test` commands in my script.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Hubert

Comment: `sudo` keeps prompting until correct.

Comment: `$?`  holds the exit code of the last command you executed.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Thanks for your quick answer. The `sudo` trick doesn't seem to work in my case, because there are multiple commands to run + some variables to interpret. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: You should really NOT use CSH for scripting new code, PLEASE! Do yourself a favour and use Bash instead on Linux. Read up on the `read` statement halfway down `man bash`.

Comment: then do `sudo csh -c 'everything here'`.